# Eloquent belongsToMany withPivot mapping

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, pivot

I've inherited 4 MySQL tables:

**listings**
-id
-description
...

**locations**
-id
-listing_id

**guides**
-id
-name
....

**guide_location**
-id
-guide_id
-location_id

Listing=>(many) Locations
Guide=>(many) Locations=>(1) Listing

Listing, Location and Guide each is its own model in a Laravel Dingo application. Here's the setup:

```
//Listing model
public function locations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Location');
}
```

Then

```
//Location model
public function guides()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Guide');
}
public function listing()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Listing');
}
```

And

```
//Guide model
public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Location');
}
```

I've added a column to **guide_location** and I want to return it when I select a Guide from the database.

So now:

**guide_location**
-id
-guide_id
-location_id
*-position*

I tried adding `->withPivot('position')` to both `belongsToMany()` statements in the Guide and Location models but it's not working, I'm not seeing the new column.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, if you've just added a column, why do you need to pivot to another table? Or is it that you've introduced a 5th table, yet, and when you query for the `Guide` which returns `Guide Location`, then you also want that `Guide Location` to return with the result of it's `position relationships`?

Comment: Maybe withPivot isn't the command I need? From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) it suggested this was the only way to pull in this other value, unless I'm misreading it- "By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:"

Comment: That's only true when you're using a Pivot table, but you're not in this case, `guide_location` isn't a pivot table, nor is it even Polymorphic, it just has many constraints. if I query `$guide = Guide::find($id)->with('guide_location');` I would expect to see a `position` column on my return, given the code you're provided above. Do you in fact have a `position` table that you're attempting to join through the `guide_location` table?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe `guide_location` is a pivot table. It's mapping guide IDs to location IDs, nothing else (except the new column I added). Am I not reading [this](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/) right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, `->withPivot()` was working, I just was not seeing the result because it was in `location.pivot.position`, not `location.position`. Dumb.

Hope this helps others.